# Python access to objects created by Java-Application during runtime

Tags: java, python, python-3.5

I have a Java-Application given as a .jar-file and a third-party progam, which has a Python-API. The workflow is that I start the java-Application insert there some data and also some new objects get created. After that I want to press a button maybe, which executes the Python script to transfer this data to the third-party programm. The Python script needs data stored in the created objects.

So my questions are:
(1) is it possible to give the Python script an array as an input argument?

or
(2) is there a way to give the Python script a Java object as an input and the script could access the methods, child objects and variables of the given Object?
e.g.: that I could write something like this in the Python script:

```
data = JavaObject //the Object the Python script received
i = data.object1.getFoo()
print(i)
```

or
(3) is there a way to embed the Python script into the .jar-file that i can execute it and the Python script has access to the classes and methods of the .jar-file?
e.g.:

```
i = Object.object1.getChild().getValue() //Object should be any object
                                         //which i created previously
```

I think that Jython would have been good for this kind of task, but it only supports Python 2.7 and due to the third-party API i need to work with Python 3.5
If necessary it would be possible to use Python 3.3 or 3.4, but only if needed.

EDIT: If possible the Java-Application should be executeable without Python installed, but that is not necessary would just be a nice feature

Comment: Don't do this. Use a common serialisation format, JSON comes to mind.

Comment: We also thought about that and a test version is also already implemented, but when we create a lot of data it takes very long to create a JSON-file. Reading the JSON-file with python is very easy and also fast, but Java is the problem. So we thought, that reading the data directly from the Java-Application would be faster, but it is hard to find something about that.

Comment: There are fast JSON libraries for Java. But that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching and discussing with colleagues, I think I can answer my own question.

You can use [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/index.html) to get variables and objects from java.
 After reading [the tutorial](https://www.py4j.org/getting_started.html) everything else was easy. It does what i want and i can export the data quicker now.
It is also possible to write some data back into the Java-Application. If you have implemented setter-methods you can call them from Python.